# Using every() to check if an Array contains all the elements of another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array that changes on each click. Every time that click happens, I need to find out if the Array contains any of the sequences on a set of Arrays. This is the given set of Arrays I am comparing that Array with:

```
const combos = [
      [0, 5, 3],
      [0, 8, 2],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 2],
];
```

This is how I am trying to compare them:

```
const playerCombo = ( arr ) => {
      //First sort the Array
      const sorted = arr.sort();

      //Initialize the hasWon variable
      let hasWon = '';

      //For each combo Array...
      for( let combo of boardCtrl.combos ){
        if( sorted.length > 2 ) {
          hasWon = combo.every((e)=> sorted.includes(e));
        }
      }

      return hasWon;

    }
```

But the results are not very consistent and only work sometimes.

Comment: `hasWon` is overwriting, so that is the end of the loop. You probably just want to `if( sorted.length > 2 ) {
          if(!combo.every((e)=> sorted.includes(e))){ return false;
        } } return true;`

Comment: Please include the sample input and output.

Comment: If you're going to be comparing each individual member to see if it's included in a separate array, what's the point of sorting the array?

Comment: you are checking if there is a zero, it is not checking if there is two zeros. So if array A is `[0,0,5]` it would pass with `[0,5,3]`

Comment: Comparing primitive value Arrays is simple, but I'm concerned about the sorting. It's likely you could stringify, compare, and call it a day. This only works if the combos are not allowed to be in random order, so... are they?

Comment: Just an observation... If you are sorting the array before comparing to `combos`, you will never get a match for the first two arrays in `combos` because they are not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you expect:

```js
const boardCtrl = {
  combos:[[0, 5, 3], [0, 8, 2], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
}
const testArray = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 8, 2], [1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 3]];
const shouldFail = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 8, 2], [1, 7, 2], [0, 5, 3]];
const playerCombo = array => {
  const bc = boardCtrl.combos;
  let l = bc.length, n = 0;
  if(array.length !== l){
    return false;
  }
  for(let combo of bc){
    for(let a of array){       
      if(a.every(e => combo.includes(e)))n++;
    }
  }
  return n === l;
}
console.log(playerCombo(testArray));
console.log(playerCombo(shouldFail));
```